# Simple stat questions. (t sample..)

Tags: hypothesis-testing

[image]

I have a final tomorrow.. please save me!!

so for (a), it's two sided and H0= m=6.8 and Ha= m is not 6.8

but the problem is (b). how can I calculate t value without confidence level?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Please show more of an attempt at part (b), or at the least explain your thinking more clearly. Showing an answer to a different part -- without any working or discussion -- just suggests you have been an answer to that part; it doesn't demonstrate effort the part you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you're going to use a one-sample t-test to determine if your sample mean of 7.1 is significantly different from your population mean of 6.8. Your response to Part A is correct.

For Part B, calculate the following:

t = [(sample mean - population mean)/sample standard deviation]*√n

where n = number of observations in the sample, or 150

t = [(7.1 - 6.8)/0.23]*√150

t = 1.304*√150 = 15.97

Now, to determine if the answer is statistically significant, calculate degrees of freedom (df):

df = n - 1

df = 149

Now see if 15.97 is greater than the critical value of .05. You'll need a t-distribution table to do this. In most cases, tables don't have specific values above 100, so go with the number closest to your df. However, never choose a number greater than your df. For example, if your table has critical values for df = 100 and df = 150, you'd need to choose 100 in this case as it is more conservative. (Some may probably disagree on this point and call me too stringent.)

The critical value of t at .05 (two-tailed) for df = 100 is 1.984 (I'm referencing this table: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf).

15.97 > 1.984

Reject H0.

The sample suggests students sleep more than 6.8 hours per day on average.

Comment: how nice! I am really appreciated of it. Thank you! I paid 70 dollars for this question to statistic experts and they got wrong.

Comment: @HappySnowman -- please don't give complete answers to routine bookwork, especially not immediately. (For all you know this person is doing an exam *right now*.) Please read our [help/on-topic], in particular the part relating to homework and also read the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) which explains that it is generally preferable to offer guidance and hints (and even then, if the poster displays a particular sense of urgency, it doesn't hurt to wait a couple of hours). After a day or two a somewhat more complete answer may be okay.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to the community, so I had no idea about this policy. From my impression, this student was asking a question from a study guide.

Comment: That's the impression I had as well (on the other hand, if I was trying to get someone to do the parts of my exam I had trouble with, that's the impression I'd seek to give). Nevertheless, let's assume it's exactly what it appears -- even so, it's better for the student if they participate in the progression to the answer (if students could remember what people wrote, they'd ask less of the material that's already in their textbook and notes -- instead, you remember what you do) - and the guidelines on how to answer these don't only refer to actual homework.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to the site!  (There's no need to do anything with this answer, but it's something to keep in mind for future answers.)